# Fail to define a Class in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp

I was following the example on *Clojure in Action* Page 326,

```
 (defn new-object [klass]
  (fn [command & args]
    (condp = command
      :class klass)))
```

Then I typed: `(def cindy (new-object Person))`

It gives me: `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: Person in this context, compiling:(/Users/sdfsd/clj/testlein/src/testlein/sdf:22:12)`

If I change Person to "Person" or 'Person, it works. But I believe that is not the right way to solve this problem because Person should be a class and "Person" is :name of the class. Could someone please tell me why I am having this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You have to import the class, http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 (import package-and-name-of-your-person-class)
```

Or without import, use as parameter in the function call package-and-name-of-your-person-class instead of Person

```
(def cindy (new-object package-and-name-of-your-person-class))
```